# Use bash script to convert DHCP IP to static IP

Tags: networking, server, bash, vmware, dhcp

I am looking for a script that takes the IP address my ubuntu server instance receives and converts it to a static configuration. It should use all the information my server receives from the DHCP server like DNS, Default Gateway, netmask etc.

I looked on GitHub, forums and google but I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 1):

Not so hard to do BUT:
The ip your dhcp server has given to your server will, a day, be given to another dhcp client.
And you will get an error for ip address conflict.

For static ip on your server, you should choose an ip from outside the dhcp ip range.

Comment: Thanks for your response! My DHCP server checks if another device is using the IP before it gives it out to any device. So I don't think that would be a problem!

Comment: But then choose any static IP and you are fine. That makes no sense to convert the DHCP settings to a static IP setting every time. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: It happened a couple of times now that an IP suddenly changed because he got a new IP after a reboot

Comment: If you have control of the DHCP server, you can set static lease. If you don't, you can use static ip on your server. I f you have to use DHCP, then you must adapt your configuration at each new IP. I don't see how converting DHCP settings to a static configuration would help. Use a domain name. I don't know.

Comment: I appreciate your replies, but they are not really answering my question. Thanks anyway.